# Send HTML formatted email with data from spreadshhets

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've read several threads about aumatically sending emails with App Scripts and creating a HTML with data from spreadsheets and I achieved to do both things, but I'm failing to connect the pieces so I can:

**With data from my spreadsheet complete a HTML template and send an email.**

I made this function to collect the data from the spreadsheet:

```
function getnombre() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  // the sheet I'm working on
  var firstRow = sheet.getRange("A1");
  return firstRow.getValues()[0] //.
}
```

Then in the HTML file I call the function to complete with the name of the costumer in the HTML:

```
   <? var nombre = getnombre(); ?>

                           <h1><span style="font-size:15px">Hola <?= nombre ?></span><br>
```

Finally I can see the HTML by publishing it:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('TestMail3') // where template is the name of our html file!
  .evaluate();
}
```

But here is where I'm lost and I can't send the HTML by mail. I tried using the next code, but the HTML is not sent with the name of the customer:

```
    var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Mail3').getContent();  
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "test@gmail.com",
    subject: "Oferta de compra",
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  }
```

Comment: In terms of troubleshooting; what happens if you change `var nombre = getnombre();` to a static value? Does the static value appear in the email? Try to pinpoint where your script is failing. Either in acquiring the name or in inserting the value in the HTML.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer

Publishing the HTML is working well (the function doGet, with the evaluate at end  applies the logic of the functions and variables inside the HTML code). The sendemail function sends the html code but it doesn't recognices functions iside of it. When I define the variable as a static value (e.g.: var nombre = "Jose") it doesn't shows that name.

What I'm trying to find is way to insert the evaluation of the HTML code insde the SendEmail function.

Comment: Try `var htmlBody=doGet()`

Comment: Did you forget to evaluate it? `var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Mail3').evaluate().getContent()`

Comment: @I'-'I htmlBody=doGet() just sends the email with the text HtmlOutput

Comment: @ThumChoonTat I think that Evaluate and GetContect don't work together. I get this error: TypeError: Cannot find function evaluate in object HtmlOutput. (line 43, file "Code")

Comment: ``=doGet().getContent()``

Comment: @GermanAcedo sorry you need to get the `HtmlTemplate` object, `evaluate` it and then `getContent`. So it will be `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Mail3').asTemplate().evaluate().getContent()` or `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Mail3').evaluate().getContent()`

Comment: @ThumChoonTat Thank you very much for your help. I left this project on hold until today. The second line is the correct one that work for me (HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Mail3').evaluate().getContent()) as soon as I have a proper code I will post it.

Thanks again!